# Prevent arrow keys from breaking down dot command

Tags: vim

I am trying to find replacement for multi cursors plugin and found out `cgn` command pretty useful. However, there is undesirable behavior using arrow keys during insert mode. Sometimes there is no need to change the whole search entry (e.g. fix typo) so the arrow keys are necessary in that case. To reproduce the "bug" you can type `tabe` and then `3ifoobar<Enter><Esc>/foo<Enter>cgn<End>bar<Esc>.`
No matter what movement you will use: arrow keys or key like `<End>` - powerful dot command stops working. I mean it just inserts text written after movement at the same position instead of changing the next search entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to support redo, consists in using `<C-G>U` before `<right>` and `<left>`. This requires `has('patch-7.4.849')`

If you need to move to the end of the line, you'll need to count. If you need to move to the next line, you'll loose redo.

Comment: Since with `cgn` I usually use only arrow keys this tip is very useful, thank you. Adding a few mappings for convenience and the issue is outdated.